# grep with sed inplace

Tags: sed, grep

i want to replace clk in set_input to clk_new.

On terminal it works fine:

```
grep set_input abc.tcl | grep -w clk | sed 's/clk/clk_new/g'
```

But once i use inplace, save changes to file it changes all in file.i.e

```
grep set_input abc.tcl | grep -w clk | sed -i 's/clk/clk_new/g' abc.tcl
set_input -clock clk_new -delay 0.2
set_input -clock clk_new -delay 0.5
set_output -clock clk_new -delay 0.2
```

Comment: can you add sample input file and expected output? all of it can be done using `sed` itself.. see [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/sed/3120/address-and-address-range/13753/lines-matching-regular-expression-pattern#t=201608221331163191979) for examples..

Comment: `sed -i 's/clk/clk_new/g' abc.tcl` is acting directly on the contents of file `abc.tcl` and not output from grep..

Answer (score 1):

Any time you find yourself chaining greps+seds you have the wrong approach. In this case all you need is GNU sed (which you're already using due to `-i`) for word boundaries:

```
sed -E -i 's/(set_input.*)\<clk\>/\1clk_new/g' abc.tcl
```

Comment: Thanks @Ed Morton, your solution works with slight modification. sed -i 's/\(set_input.*\)\<clk\>/\1clk_new/g' abc.tcl

Comment: sed -i 's/\\(set_input.*\\)\<clk\>/\1clk_new/g' abc.tcl     Added back slash.

Comment: That's an alternative to specifying `-E` but neither is properly portable.

Comment: @triplee the script is using GNU sed for word boundaries and `-i` so portability's already out the window.

Comment: BSD `sed` supports `-i` as well, though with a slightly different syntax, but I guess you're right. Maybe the OP wants to explain why they didn't want to use `-E` anyway.

Answer (score 0):

-i option specifies that files are to be edited in-place is used for replace statement on file.

You don't need grep statements.

Try this code:

```
$ sed -i 's/clk/clk_new/g' abc.tcl
```

Comment: okan ,i want to replace in set_input command clk not set_output command.So ur solution doesn't work

Comment: @Yash: But it is trivial to make it work: `sed -i '/set_input -clock clk -delay/ s/clk/clk_new/' abc.tcl`.  This looks for lines containing `set_input` with the original name `clk`, and changes the `clk` to `clk_new`.  The advantage of this is that if you accidentally run it on a script that has already been edited, it will not create a `clk_new_new` reference.